# rewrite arrow function in regular js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have the following react return:

```
return (
     <div className='App'>
        <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
           <input
              value={this.state.input}
              onChange={(e)=> this.setState({input:e.target.value})}
              type='text'
           />
        </form>
        <ul>
           {items}
        </ul>
     </div>
  );
```

I'm trying to rewrite the onChange line to be a regular js function and want to within this function console.log(e) as well as to setState.  Can that be done?

Comment: Probably, but why?

Comment: Why yes. Yes it can be done

Comment: dude you asked this yesterday

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Not sure if it is too late but check BabelJS, that's exactly what it does: transpiles ES6 into ES5. https://babeljs.io/repl/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var self = this
return (
 <div className='App'>
    <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
       <input
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={function(e) { 
              console.log(e)
              self.setState({input:e.target.value})
           }}
          type='text'
       />
    </form>
    <ul>
       {items}
    </ul>
 </div>
);
```

this should work

Comment: thank you.  How come this is undefined in the onChange function - shouldn't it refer back to either the form or the input box?

Comment: To be equivalent to the arrow function in the question, there should be a `return` before `self.setState`. But for this code, we know that [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) returns nothing, so leaving out `return` is clearer.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  Do you know why 'this' is undefined inside the anonymous function?

Comment: in React events this doesn't refer to the dom element like in normal html,if you want to access the dom element you should use react refs